# Move/Rename a lot of files with specific file size

Tags: files, batch, batch-rename

I recovered a lot of pictures (1000+) from a bad SD Card. All except 75 which seems to be 'broken'. I ran a program to get all the pictures reading at a lower level and I found out I got all the pictures including the ones that are not readable in the SD Card, the problem is that they were recovered with different names and a lot are duplicated.

I want to find the file (if there's more than one, just get the first) in the 'good' folder with the exact same size each file in the 'bad' folder has, and rename it with its name.

I ran this command `ls -lR | egrep -v '^d' | awk '$5==5040057{print}'`

and I got this result

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  5040057 Apr  6 04:47 _MG_2443.JPG
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 5040057 Apr  6 04:47 f11146176.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 5040057 Apr  6 04:47 f12072256.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 5040057 Apr  6 04:47 f14834560.jpg
```

Edit: It doesn't show in the result from the command, but the folder structure is as follows:

```
Recovery:
 |- Bad ( containing _MG_XXXX.JPG files )
 |- Good ( Containing fXXXXXXXX.jpg files )
```

Where the first one _IMG_2443.JPG is the bad image and any of the following are good (those are the candidates to be renamed or moved). So for the previous example I would like that for example file 'f11146176.jpg' to be renamed in the Good folder as '_MG_2443.JPG' so I can check it later and replace it on the bad folder.

Is there a way to run a command to do that automatically for all the pictures? Thanks

Comment: File size is not a good way to do this. Are you sure the files are identical? Do they have the same result for `md5sum file.jpg`?

Comment: @terdon my idea of using the file size is the first that came to my mind.. any better solution would be great :) Thanks for your comment

Comment: @terdon so I checked the md5sum and they are different (I guess that could explain why the original picture cannot be open. So I think it's safe enough to use the file size

Comment: No it's not, really. It is perfectly possible that you have two files with the same size and completely different contents. Are the  creation dates also the same? Presumably they are unless they've kept the date from the camera.

Comment: @terdon creation date seems to be the same, yes. but for example for 1 particular picture I can't find the 'good' one using the size (maybe that one went missing because of the bad sd card.)

Comment: OK. I will write an answer using the file size but be warned that it can result in loss of data if two files have the same size but different contents. Now, please [edit] and clarify your question. You mention two folders but your `ls` lists the contents of one. Are the 'good' and 'bad' in different folders or not? Which folder contains the duplicates? The 'good' or the 'bad'? Can you give a more complete example? Also, can we assume that your file names contain no spaces or new lines?

Comment: @terdon I've added the extra information you requested. 2 folders with different name patterns for each, and no spaces in names. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14351/discussion-between-terdon-and-serpro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File size is not a good way of determining duplicates. You can have two files with the exact same size but different contents. This means that it is quite likely that this approach will fail. That said, the following will do what you asked for.

**Important:** this assumes your file names have no spaces and no new lines.

```bsh
find bad -iname "*.jpg" -printf "%s %f\n" | while read -r bs bf; do 
  find good/ -iname "*.jpg" -printf "%s %f\n" | while read -r gs gf; do 
    [ $bs -eq $gs ] && echo "mv good/$gf good/$bf"; 
  done 
done
```

#### Explanation

- `find bad -iname "*.jpg" -printf "%s %f\n"` : find all files whose name ends in `.jpg` or `.JPG` in the `bad` directory and print their size and file name.
- `while read -r bs bf; do` : read each line of the output above, saving the file's size as `$bs` and its name as `$bf`.
- The second `find ... | while ...; done` does exactly the same for the `good` directory, saving the file's size as `$gs` and its name as `$gf`.
- `[[ $bs -eq $gs ]] && echo "mv good/$gf good/$bf";` : If the bad file's size is the same as the good file's size, rename the good file using the bad file's name. If this does what you expect, remove the echo and change the line to simply `mv good/"$gf" good/"$bf"`. Note that **this will keep the *last* 'bad' file name as the final name for the 'good' file.**

---

I want to stress that this is not safe, different files can have the exact same size and completely different contents. Instead of using this naive approach, you might be better off using a program that is specifically designed to compare images. I've never used any such software but a 3 minute search turned up [DupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/). I suggest you try it first:

> [DupeGuru](http://www.hardcoded.net/dupeguru_pe/) : dupeGuru Picture Edition (PE for short) is a tool to find duplicate pictures on your computer. dupeGuru PE is a big brother of dupeGuru.
>
> This software works like dupeGuru, but is specialized for duplicate pictures matching. dupeGuru PE runs on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux.